# Which resolution for a picture background for two panoramaItem

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

I created a WP apps with a panorama containing two panoramaItem.
I would like to set a background picture.

I don't know which resolution i need to use for two panoramaitem.

Anyone could help me please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use a properly sized image in your application. The recommended dimensions for a Panorama background image is a height of 800 pixels and a width less than 2000 pixels. (I have often use a 800 x 900, with good result, it also depends on the content of the image!)

If a Panorama control is using an image for the background, its Build Action should be set to Resource; otherwise, it will not appear immediately when the application is first displayed. Setting the Build Action to Content would cause it to be loaded asynchronously.